# Pandas groupby using agg and apply at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,3,2], 'year': ['2020', '2014', '2002', '2020', '2016', '2014'], 'e': [True, False, True, True, False, True], 'val': [100,200,300, 200, 300, 200]})

id  year      e  val
0   1  2020   True  100
1   1  2014  False  200
2   1  2002   True  300
3   2  2020   True  200
4   3  2016  False  300
5   2  2014   True  200
```

And I want the following information:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x[x['e']]['year'].min())
id
1    2002
2    2014
3     NaN
```

And

```
df.groupby('id').val.sum()
id
1    600
2    400
3    300
```

My question is if it is possible to return both of these in the same group by? Or will I have to do separately and then merge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do it with `apply`

```
s = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.loc[x['e'], 'year'].min(),x['val'].sum()],index=['myear','sumy']))
Out[321]: 
   myear   sumy
id             
1   2002  600.0
2   2014  400.0
3    NaN  300.0
```

Comment: Please, correct that chained indexing....  `x.loc[x['e'], 'year'].min()`  I know it doesn't matter much in this example.  It just bugs me. :)

Comment: @ScottBoston: I know `apply` with `pd.Series` has its use. In this case, I think it is proper. However, whenever I see them using together, I also feel kind of uneasy the same as chain indexing :). Still, upvoted :) +1

Answer (score 2):

I think using `agg` on direct column `year` and `val` is better than `apply` with `pd.Series`

```
df_final = df.groupby('id').agg({'year': lambda x: x[df.loc[x.index, 'e']].min(), 
                                 'val': 'sum'})

Out[347]:
    year  val
id
1   2002  600
2   2014  400
3    NaN  300
```

Comment: Really interesting syntax! Might be useful in other problems, thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  
`.apply( lambda x: accuracy_score(x['success'], x['Predicted'])) ` - works.   
`.agg( acc= lambda x: accuracy_score(x['success'], x['Predicted']))`. - error. 
 :Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc).  
i tried many combination of the lambda inside the .agg and didn't succeed